# Configure Google Cloud SQL instance in Eclipse

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

The name of my instance is

> domain.com:my_project:xyz

So i actually completed the form like this :
[image: form]

But i got the following error :

[image: error]

Any ideas? Thank you so much!

I just created it like 20 mins ago may be i need to wait but i doubt that it is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance name is "domain.com:my_project:xyz", not just "xyz".